# moving elements from list of list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of list, `k=[[1,2,3],[2,5,6],[2],[1,7,8,3]]`

If there is any `list` within `list k` which has single element like `[2]` here, I want to remove it from `k`, and append/move to some different `list`.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: `k=[[1,2,3],[2,5,6],[1,7,8,3]]`  `n=[[2]]`   `n` is the arbitrary list I am appending one element to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `pop` with `idx` form `k` then `append` to `list` that you want.

Try this:

```
>>> k = [[1,2,3],[2],[3],[1,7,8]]

>>> idx = 0
>>> out = []
>>> while idx < len(k):
...    if len(k[idx])==1:
...        out.append(k.pop(idx))
...        idx -= 1
...    idx += 1
      
        
>>> k
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 7, 8]]


>>> out
[[2],[3]]
```